# Changing the Step value from Javascript

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have the following Kendo.Chart in asp.net, and I need to change the Step value when the chart data is refreshed.

e.g.

.Step(8)

to

.Step(0)

How can I do this?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart<GenericDateTimeValueDataPoint>()
                              .Name("trendchart_" + location.LocationId)
                              .Legend(legend => legend.Visible(false))
                              .ChartArea(chartArea => chartArea.Background("transparent")
                                  .Height(276))
                              .AutoBind(false)
                              .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read.Action("ProfileTrend", "Chart")
                                  .Data(@<text>function (){ var selectedTimespan = $('#duration option:selected').val(); var startDateTime = $('#startDateTimePicker').val(); var endDateTime = $('#endDateTimePicker').val() ; return { locationGuid: '@location.LocationId', timespan: selectedTimespan, startDateTime: startDateTime, endDateTime: endDateTime, timeZoneOffset: window.currentTimeZoneOffsetInHours }}</text>))
                                  .Events(ev => ev.RequestStart("viewModel.utilisationDataRequestStarted")
                                      .RequestEnd("uViewModel.utilisationDataLoaded")))
                              .SeriesDefaults(series => series.Column().Overlay(ChartBarSeriesOverlay.None))
                              .Series(series => series.Column(model => model.CollectedValue, categoryExpression: model => model.DateTimeFormattedString)
                                  .Gap(0.3)
                                  .Name("Valve Open")
                                  .Color(Lookups.GetColourAsHex(Colours.SilverGrey)))
                              .CategoryAxis(axis => axis.MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false))
                                  .Labels(labels => labels.Format("{0:d}").Step(8))
                                  .Categories()
                                  .Title(title => title.Text(DisplayText.Get("Time"))))
                              .ValueAxis(axis => axis.Numeric().Labels(labels => labels.Format("{0}%")).Line(line => line.Visible(true)).Min(0).Max(100).Title(title => title.Text(DisplayText.Get("Utilisation")))).Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip.Visible(true).Template("#=dataItem.DateTimeFormattedString#<br />#= kendo.format('{0:N2}',value) #%")))
```

Comment: What do you mean by step? Do you mean paging?

Comment: No, this is a chart is the the number of step points to display the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a callback to the `dataBound` event (which is fired every time the data is bound to your chart) and then on this callback you can change/set the `step` property. But you will need to call the `refresh` method form the kendo chart in order to have the changes applied.

The code would be similar to the following:

```
//Your code
.Events(ev => ev.RequestStart("viewModel.utilisationDataRequestStarted")
.RequestEnd("uViewModel.utilisationDataLoaded")))
.DataBound("onDataBound")))
//Your code

//Javascript
function onDataBound(arg) {
    var chart = $("ELEMENT_ID").getKendoChart();
    chart.options.axisDefaults.labels.step = 2;
    chart.refresh();
}
```

Hope it helps you.